# Shift menu of material ui to left most side of page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I want to shift the menu to the left side of the page so that there is no space in between. but no matter what i do its not shifting to left side. please suggest some solution.

[image]

following is my relevant code:

```
  <Menu
                 
                  anchorReference="anchorPosition"
                  anchorPosition={{ top: 90, left: 0 }}
                  anchorOrigin={{
                    vertical: "bottom",
                    horizontal: "left",
                  }}
                  transformOrigin={{ vertical: "top", horizontal: "left" }}
                  keepMounted
                  open={open}
                  onClose={handleClose}
                  classes={{ paper: classes.menuPaper }}
                >
```

styles for popover from classes object:

```
 menuPaper: {
backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.light,
width: "100%",
maxWidth: "unset",
  },
```

Comment: Did you try putting margin 0?

Comment: yes i did but to no avail.i think its got something to do with material ui library that i am using

Comment: Can you regenerate your problem in Codesandbox and add the link here?

Comment: will do it in a while, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out finally. there is this props margin treshold in popever. i put value its value to 0 and it worked. @Mateen was right partially, it wasn't margin but there was offset of 16 on position left. Its default value of margin threshold.it had to be overriden to 0.